# Vertical Axis in chart repeating values - SQL Reporting Services 2008

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008

Hi i have the following problem.

I'm doing a chart in SSRS 2008. I'm doing a count and the result of the count is 2.

Because of the little count the chart is repeating th values on the Y axis. This is not happening when the count is 50 for example.
[image]

How can i get rid of the repeating values 1 1 and 2 2. Of course if i set the interval to 1 the problem is fixed but if the count is 50 the interval will show from 0 to 50(0, 1, 2 ... 50 and i don't want that)

I hope someone has the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the interval property of the Y axis to resolve the issue. To set the interval property

1. Right click on the Y axis.
2. Go to Axis Properties
3. In Axis Options you will find “Interval” under “set axis scale and style” section.
4. Click on fx button and replace the `value =IIF( Fields!columnname.Value < 10,  1,  0)`

Click OK -> OK

That’s all.

Comment: Marked this as Answer because it came with the steps to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I did a workaround, i don't think this should be marked as a answer. If anyone has this problem this might help them.

Over the Interval I placed this fx: =IIF(Fields!quotevalues.Value < 10, 1, 0)

So if i have a count less than 10 the interval will be 1 by 1. If it's more than 10 the interval will be automatically set.

As i said if anyone has a better solution, it will be welcomed.

Comment: This is the only way to work around this issue that I've found.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't repeating values, you need to format the number of the y-axis to include the first decimal place. Once you do, they should read 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.

To format the numbers on the y-axis, right-click on the y-axis and go to Vertical Axis Properties. Then select Number, and increase the decimal place from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but wanted to use the row count.

This expression in the interval worked:  =IIF( CountRows() < 10,  1,  0)